# how to use testNamePattern of jest within package.json scripts field?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Honestly, `jest` of facebook has a bad document.

I want to use `jest -t xxx` to update my snapshots.

Here is my test, but no one works correctly.

1. `jest -u -t='test.tsx'`
2. `jest -u -t 'test.tsx'`
3. `jest -u -t /test.tsx/`
4. `jest -u -t=/test.tsx/`

I want to match and update snapshots test files which filename pattern like `*.test.tsx`.

How can I do that with jest `testNamePattern`?

Comment: have you tried `jest -u -t '*.test.tsx'` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First check jest --showConfig to see that you even have the option of --testNamePattern. I faced the same issue, and did not find this option in jest config.

So I changed my directory structure and used --testPathPattern option with regex. This works.

jest --testPathPattern='(tests)/spec/.*/snapshot-tests/.*'